# Debounce Time when click on button Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am new in RXJS and i want to implement debounce time when click on button.
This is my button:

```
 <button mat-mini-fab (click)="send()" [disabled]="!message.text || message.text.length === 0 || room.length === 0 || !room">
    <mat-icon>send</mat-icon>
  </button>
```

And this is my method for send:

```
public send(): void {
    this.message = { ...this.message, room: this.room, sender: this.currentUser, createdAt: new Date() };
    this.sendMessage.emit(this.message);
    this.clearMessage();
  }
```

How can i implement this, any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this with a litte trick.

```
// define a Subject
private rxjsSimulator: Subject<number> = new Subject();

// instantiate a Subscription in order to end the Subject-subscription when you leave the component
private subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();


// subscribe to the rxjs simulator
constructor() {
  this.subscription.add(
    // Here you can set your debounce time
    this.rxjsSimulator.pipe(debounceTime(1000)).subscribe(() => {
        this.triggeredSend();
      }
    )
  );
}


// map your send()-method
public send(): void {
  // uses an ever-changing value in order to always trigger the update
  this.rxjsSimulator.next(Date.now());
}


// have a sub-method that gets triggered by the subject
private triggeredSend(): void {
  this.message = {...this.message, room: this.room, sender: this.currentUser, createdAt: new Date()};
  this.sendMessage.emit(this.message);
  this.clearMessage();
}

// unsubscribe
ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Though the accepted answer works, I'd suggest not using a `Subject` but instead do it in a more reactive way.

You can easily capture the click event with the `fromEvent` function, debounce the event and then do whatever you want, instead of having to keep track of an observable.

Just get your button with a `@ViewChild('idToMyButton') button: ElementRef;` and then start listen to the click events with `fromEvent(button.nativeElement, 'click');`

The `fromEvent` will emit any time the button is clicked, so you can easily debounce it just like

```
fromEvent(button.nativeElement, 'click').pipe(
    debounceTime(250),
    tap(() => {
        // Do what needs to be done on click
    }),
    takeUntil(this.destroyed$) // Don't forget to unsubscribe
).subscribe();

// For cleanup purposes
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroyed$.next();
    this.destroyed$.complete();
}
```